# iOS 12 devices randomly wakes to Home screen and doesn't turn off again automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, sleep-wake, screen-lock

I've got an iPhone 8 and an iPad mini 4 (both running iOS 12) that both seem to have the same issue.

For some reason they randomly turn on the Home screen when they are resting, as if they have just received a push notification (although they haven't).

When they randomly turn on the Home screen, it will not turn off without manually pressing the lock button. So if this happens in the middle of the night, it just runs down the battery.

Any ideas why this might be?

Please see below screenshot of Settings app for lock on the iPhone.

[image]

Comment: Does this occur if the phones have Do Not Disturb enabled?  How are the iPad and iPhone connected (if they are)? restored from backup? Apple ID?

Comment: Ill try with DND on, it happens in frequently so will be hard to tell if DND solves the issue or that the issue just hasnt occurred. The iPad and iPhone are both linked to the same iCloud.

Comment: low power mode would lock it I think but waking up is still a mystery